# how to fetch order number, payment method and customer name according to invoice number in admin panel grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, invoice

I`m fetching invoice collection using ***Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection();*** but I also want Order number, payment method and customer name according to the invoice number. How to fetch that and display in grid?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below answer to get order number,order information,payment method and customer name based on invoice id --

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$invoiceid =15;

/* get invoice collection  */
$invoicecollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection()
                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$invoiceid)
                                                        ->getData();

/* get order number and collection with customer name */
$orderId = $invoicecollection[0]['order_id'];
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData());
echo $order->getCustomerFirstname();

/* get payment information and card type */
$payment = $order->getPayment();
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($payment->getData());
echo $payment['cc_type'];

//Get Payment Info
echo $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
echo $payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); 

?>
```

Comment: This might be correct but what I`m looking is for to fetch the order number, customer name and payment method according to invoice number on admin panel grid!